# Best way for a Node.js application to interact with an external program

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, web

I am a beginner to web development - I am building a website that requires some entries from the user, does some complicated mathematical processing on those entries, and returns the result to the client. I was thinking of implementing the mathematical stuff in another separate application which is better suited for such work (like in Java or C++ where there are good math libraries and the implementation would be more robust and faster). I was wondering what is the best way to do this, architecture-wise.

The "dummy" approach would be spawning a process from the Node.js application and waiting on its output from stdout, parsing it (probably in JSON) and then processing it before sending the result to the client. I have trouble believing that this is the best way to do this (it seems too error-prone, no proper error handling, dependent on the output, and just plain bad practice). A slightly better approach would be to have the Java or C++ application listening on a specific port and waiting for requests from the Node.js application. However this requires more thinking in terms of load-balancing (how would it scale with the number of requests?). Finally, the last approach I found online was to use a queuing system such as RabbitMQ as a way to communicate between the Node.js application and the Java application.

Typically (in a "traditional" software), implementing a separate library that holds all the math magic to which we can make calls would be a good way to go.

What is the best approach to achieve this with a Node.js/web application? There must be good practices/models/architectures/designs for such a problem. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this http://mathjs.org/ Probably you can bypass the external "math app" and do everything in Node.js but I don't know what math you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I can think of is writing a **native nodejs module**, you can use C++ and any library you have to write the code and export some APIs to be called from node's javascript.

This also allows you to package your native application as a module for nodejs, which can then be distributed and compiled/installed with npm.

Here's the [official tutorial](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) from node's website.

It isn't the easiest approach, but certainly the more elegant and mantainable one.

Answer (score 0):

IF your problem can be structured in a stateless way -- i.e. you send a request out with the data and the associated task, and then later receive the result as a response, I would probably create one angular app for the front end, and multiple node servers for the back end (IF you needed to handle many requests simultaneously).

As pointed out in the first answer below, you can put whatever parts of the problem that you want to into native code, BUT what might be much easier is to use sockets to connect to a server to do the computation, in any language, etc...   In one project I use a socket.service to handle all the communication back and forth to the servers. (The angular-fullstack generator in the next paragraph has such a skeleton socket.service piece.)

In terms of the frontend in combination with a node backend, The Yeoman generator (http://yeoman.io/generators/) for creating MEAN stack applications, using MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node - lets you quickly set up a project following best practices. And the angular-fullstack generator will give you a framework that is light years ahead in so many ways.  You can use yeoman to generate a sample application frontend (angular, express) and backend (NodeJs, MongoDB) with support for sockets, etc...

This too is not very simple, but in the end, with a few months of work, you would have a structured problem and solution that you would never outgrow.  When I first wanted to work into this space, that was the path I took.  And in truth the front-end was/is the harder part and the backend, connected with sockets, http, or whatever has gotten to be much simpler. In terms of servers, AWS, or even just nginx on Linux through DigitalOcean or many others is inexpensive and flexible.

I hope this helps.